# SQL: Return the values from an array where some of them don't exist in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

What i'm looking for, if its even possible, is a SQL Query that replaces this method so i don't have to do a query for each value in the array:

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($array as $product) {
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE product_id = :value LIMIT 1)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':value', $product);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($row = $stmt->fetch())
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

Syntax can be wrong but something like this (basically is to return the products id from the array that doesn't have a record in the table):

```
$products = array(1,2,3);
$array = join(',', array_fill(0, count($products), '?'));   
SELECT product_id WHERE product_id IN ($array) NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE product_id IN ($array))
```

Is there a way to get this or i still need to use the loop?

Comment: Where does the `$array` came from? It is from an input or another sql ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Edited :)

Comment: Well, and where does `$products` came from ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos forgot that one sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you’re looking for an anti-join. If you can insert `$products` into a temp table, you can use `not exists` to get product ids that are not in the table:

```
select * from temp_product_ids t
where not exists (
    select 1 from products p
    where p.id = t.product_id
)
```

Another approach is to get all the product ids that do exist

```
select id from products where id in ( $my_products )
```

and to use [`array_diff`](https://secure.php.net/array_diff) to see which values are missing

```
$missing_products = array_diff($my_products,$database_products);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use the "in" query to solve this question. You would need to turn your array into a comma-delimited list (we'll call it productString), which would make your SQL statement look like:

```
"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE product_id in (:productString))"
```

where product string looks like "product_id_1, product_id_2, product_id_7, etc." This would give you one query with a variable resultSet based on the list of product_id's which you provided.